# Running a maven project on an application server

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, maven, m2eclipse

i want to create a web project that i can run on an application server .
So what archetype and groupid i have to choose?

Thank you in advace

Comment: What framework(s) do you want to use? What servlet spec? What app server? Do you *need* an archetype?

Answer (score 0):

An archetype which contains a sample Maven Webapp project.

```
archetypeGroupId: org.apache.maven.archetypes
archetypeArtifactId :maven-archetype-webapp
```

If you have preference to some framework/app server you may get more option by using the following command.

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

Comment: I used this parameters (archetypeGroupId: org.apache.maven.archetypes
archetypeArtifactId :maven-archetype-webapp). but i can't run on a server ,

Comment: That's just for creating the project. To Deploy it to your Server you have to find a Maven plugin for your server. For instance, tomcat:deploy for Tomcat.